# What is the proper terminology for referring to a coterminal angle between 0 and 2π?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

Let's say I have an angle ∠A.

There are an infinite number of positive and negative angles coterminal to ∠A. However, only one of these coterminal angles is in the range 0 to 2π.

Is there a specific term for referring to a coterminal angle between 0 and 2π that's more concise than "the coterminal angle between 0 and 2π"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called the **principal value** (or **principal angle**, to better fit your case).

Of course in your case you must first state that "the principal values are the values in the range $[0,2\pi)$" before using it, as for example the principal values for the arguments of complex numbers are usually defined as the values in the range $[-\pi,\pi)$.